# How do I install ImageMagick devel libraries on Fedora?

Tags: c++, gcc, imagemagick, fedora, yum

I have already installed several packages that would seem appropriate:

```
yum install ImageMagick ImageMagick-devel ImageMagick-c++
```

but still I do not have the Magick++.h file.  What package am I supposed to be looking for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On `Fedora` you can find packages that provide certain files with `yum provides`.  So for your needs, try:

```
$ yum provides '*/Magick++.h'
```

On my Fedora 19 system, the repos show that `GraphicsMagick-c++-devel` and `ImageMagick-c++-devel` packages have that file.

Comment: Oh okay. I'd tried `yum provides` but missed out the `*/`. Makes all the diff.